# Type ImageButton not found in xmlns Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, imagebutton

Refer to [this documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/imagebutton)

> The ImageButton displays an image and responds to a tap or click that
>   directs an application to carry out a particular task.

Error: Type ImageButton not found in xmlns in this code:

```
<Grid>
        <ImageButton Source="XamarinLogo.png"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Image Source="word.png" Aspect="Fill"/>
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" FontSize="20" TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"
    XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" Text="{Binding Word}" BackgroundColor="{Binding BoxColor}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Forms did you install? The `ImageButton` was added quite recently

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Xamarin.Forms 3.1.0.69729 and Prism 7.1.0.172pre

Comment: Then that is the problem. The `ImageButton` was introduced in Xamarin.Forms 3.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As deduced from the comments, you are using an older version of Xamarin.Forms. You should upgrade your packages to at least version 3.4, which is the version that [introduced](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-forms-3-4-0-say-hello-to-imagebutton/) the `ImageButton` control.

The Prism version, in this case, is not of importance.

Answer (score 0):

The [ImageButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/imagebutton) is only available in Xamarin.Forms 3.4.

Check your version, most likely is outdated and ImageButton is not available in lower versions